# Minimal value of a sum

Tags: calculus

Product of $3$ positive numbers is $192$.

One of the numbers is twice the size of the other.

What is the minimum value of their sum?

So I got $A\times2B\times b=192$, and $A+2B+B=?$

I am pretty sure I'm supposed to isolate $A$ in the first equation and get $192/2B^2$.

But I'm not sure which value to minimize in the second equation?

Comment: Try replacing A in the second equation with $\frac{192}{2B^2}$  That gives f(B) = $\frac{192}{2B^2} + 3B$  Do you know how to find the minimum?

Comment: Hmm I tried that yesterday and it didn't work. Tried it today and it worked! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You want to minimise $x+2x+y = 3x+y$ given that $x\cdot 2x\cdot y = 2x^2y = 192 \implies x^2y = 96$.  We can use the AM-GM inequality in this form:
$$ \frac{\frac32x+\frac32x+y}3 \ge \sqrt[3]{\frac94 x^2y} = \sqrt[3]{\frac94 \cdot 96} = 6$$

$$\therefore 3x+y \ge 18, \quad \text{with equality when } \frac32 x=y \implies x = 4, y=6.$$

Answer (score 0):

The A.M-G.M inequality should help here. In symbols, the inequality says that for all real numbers $a1,a2,...,a_n$,
$$\frac {a_1+a_2+...+a_n}{n} \ge(a_1a_2...a_n)^\frac{1}{n}$$
Here let $a_1$ $a_2$ $a_3$ be the three numbers. Hence
$$\frac{a_1+a_2+a_3}{3}\ge(a_1a_2a_3)^{\frac{1}{3}}$$
Also let $a_2=2a_1$ Hence we get,
$$\begin{align}
\frac{a_1+2a_1+a_3}{3}&\ge(192)^{\frac{1}{3}}\\
\Rightarrow \frac{3a_1+a_3}{3}&\ge(192)^{\frac{1}{3}}\\
\Rightarrow S&\ge3(192)^{\frac{1}{3}}
\end{align}$$
Now the minimum value will occur if $a_3=3a_1$

Comment: The AM-GM you first wrote gives equality iff $a_1 = a_2 = a_3$, which is clearly not the case here.